# What are some of the more efficient ways to handle queries?

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment, I'm handling them like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("...");
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
    ...
 }
```

What are the more practical ways to go about this?

Comment: I usually use fetch_object, but normally you would use a database abstraction layer together with an orm library. At least for bigger projects.

Answer (score 2):

My question to you is: what's *impractical* about that?

It seems the ideal paradigm for processing your result set one row at a time. If that's what you need then that's what you need.

My only advice would be to ensure you only ask for the columns you need, and that you let the database do what it's best at. In other words, if you want aggregated results, that's something the database should do (rather than bringing down *all* records and aggregating on the client).

---

Regarding the need to do it all at once, there's not a lot of difference between something like (pseudo-code):

```
array_of_array = fetch_all()
```

and

```
array_of_array = empty
while (array = fetch_one()):
    array_of_array.push (array);
```

Certainly not enough for the language developers to think it necessary, given the possible `fetch` functions found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php).

If you really need that functionality, you could probably code it up yourself. That's why most languages provide the ability to create user-defined functions, after all :-)

Comment: Well, there are instances where one *doesn't* want to process one row at a time; rather, it'd be convenient to have the result stored as an array for later consumption. As it stands, if I want that functionality, I have to create the empty array and then go through and push each result; it seems like there ought to be a more convenient way to go about that.